# Which noun does the that-clause modify?

Tags: clauses

> The leak detection algorithm is suggested based on rules, historical
> context, and user position **that** can manage to detect ten different
> forms of ingestion, such as normal, low, extreme, and anomalous

The sentence from an article named "IoT and Cloud Computing Issues, Challenges and Opportunities: A Review". Here is the [link](https://journal.qubahan.com/index.php/qaj/article/view/36) where can get the PDF file including the sentence above which is on page 4. 
The that-clause modifies "The leak detection algorithm", but I mistook it for modifying "user position".
What is the key to determine the that-clause modifies which noun?

Comment: When you quote text in a question, please provide information about the source- ideally a link to the original document. This helps us to assess the overall context of the text.

Comment: @rann rann The added link doesn't lead to the text you quoted.

Comment: It can't modify the subject "the leak detection algorithm", that would be impossible. It is ambiguous, but the salient interpretation is that it modifies "rules, historical context, and user position"

Answer (score 0):

It is not a very well written sentence.  My guess is that it's intended to modify "leak detection algorithm", but actually modifies "rules, historical context, and user position". The word **suggested** seems to serve no purpose, and **that** would be better replaced by **and**.

> The leak detection algorithm is based on rules, historical context, and user position and can manage to detect ten different forms of ingestion, such as normal, low, extreme, and anomalous